# How to set a file size threshold for Apache deflate module?

Tags: apache, compression, filesize, deflate, threshold

I want to stop Apache from compressing small files, since the compressed result is larger than the original file due to overheads. Is there a way to set a threshold for the file size in Apache Deflate Module?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear there's any way to set a minimum file size in mod_deflate (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html)

However you can skip compressing images as it won't actually do compression.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, but I don't have many images. My main issue is that one of my JSON files is too small and the compression makes it several times larger. In general it is not a big problem, since it is still small. I have read somewhere that there is a way to set a file size threshold, but I couldn't find how to do it, so I raised this question.